# Why I didn't get JSON response?

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
  <?php
  include ('config.php');
  $stringData = $_POST['dataString']; 
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id_fk='$stringData'");

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      $user=$row['user_id'];
      $time=$row['time'];
      $comment=$row['comment_content'];
      $respond=array(
          'user'=>$user,
          'time'=>$time,
          'comment'=>$comment
      );
      echo   json_encode ($respond);
  }
  ?>
```

I have this script and can't firgure out, what doesn't work here and why response isn't JSON?

In Firebug shows that response:

```
{"user":"890","time":"2013-08-15 20:34:02","comment":"What's up?"}
{"user":"878","time":"2013-08-15 23:35:45","comment":"opa"}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON answer parsing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259276/json-answer-parsing-error)

Comment: You should parse the JSON string, otherwise it's just a string.

Comment: @undefined if I alert response right now it should show [object Object]? At this moment actually it doesn't alert anything.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to combine your json data into a single object/array before encoding it:

```
$output = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      $user=$row['user_id'];
      $time=$row['time'];
      $comment=$row['comment_content'];
      $respond=array(
          'user'=>$user,
          'time'=>$time,
          'comment'=>$comment
      );
      $output[] =  json_encode ($respond);
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

also adding headers might help, if the wrong content type is detected:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```

just make sure you set those, before echoing anything...